# remove unwanted list item from selection

Tags: jquery

I have a jsFiddle that shows text when certain check boxes are selected.  If a list item is "evil", I don't want to display it.

http://jsfiddle.net/mgaRw/15/

```
<ul class="filterThis">

<li class="red evil circle">
<h3>red evil circle</h3>
</li>

<li class="red circle">
<h3>red circle</h3>
</li>
.
.
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead ofselecting all list elements:

```
var targets = $('.filterThis li')
```

you only select ones that are not evil:

```
var targets = $('.filterThis li:not(.evil)')
```

Comment: Isn't `evil` supposed to be an example to show that any `li` with an extra class should not be displayed?

Comment: @sachleen `evil` can be `foo` or `bar`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$(this).is('.evil'))
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgaRw/16/)

As a sidenote, an UL (you don't need uppercase for tags anymore, it's not 1990) can't have a P as a child, but should have LI elements as children, so your markup is invalid.

I'd probably do this:

```
$('.filters input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var checks1 = $('input[type="checkbox"]', '.filters ul:first').map(function() {
        if (this.checked) return this.value;
    }),
        checks2 = $('input[type="checkbox"]', '.filters ul:last').map(function() {
        if (this.checked) return this.value;
    });
    $('.filterThis li').each(function(i,elm) {
        var classes = elm.className.split(' '), 
            show = false;
        if (classes.length==2 && checks1.length>0 && checks2.length>0) {
            if ($.inArray(classes[0], checks1)!=-1 || $.inArray(classes[0], checks2)!=-1 && 
                $.inArray(classes[1], checks1)!=-1 || $.inArray(classes[1], checks2)!=-1) show=true;
        }
        $(elm).toggle(show);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgaRw/20/) (even fixed the markup)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to revise your iterator like below to check if the input length is 0

```
$.each(classList, function(index, item){
   var inputItem = $('input[value="'+item+'"]');
   if (!inputItem.length || inputItem.not(':checked').length) {
     include = false;
     return false;  
   }
});
```

**DEMO:**  http://jsfiddle.net/mgaRw/19/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you dynamically create the `<li>` element instead of filtering? Don't make simple things complicated!

```
<ul class="filters" id="shapes">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="circle">Circle</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="square">Square</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="triangle">Triangle</li>
</ul>

<ul class="filters" id="colors">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="red">Red</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="blue">Blue</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="yellow">Yellow</li>
</ul>

<ul class="result"></ul>​
```

After a few cups of [Coffee](http://www.coffeescript.org):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on 'click', ->
  $list = $('ul.result')

  $list.empty()

  $.each $('#shapes').find('input'), ->
    return true unless $(this).is(':checked')
    shape = $(this).val()
    $.each $('#colors').find('input'), ->
      return true unless $(this).is(':checked')
      color = $(this).val()
      $list.append $('<li>').html("#{shape} #{color}")​​​​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrbpg/6/)